# circular progress bar with canvas arcs - not working on scroll-up javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, scroll, automatic-ref-counting

This is my first post (I'm sorry if a make any mistake).
I am trying to make something like a "circular progress bar" with canvas. I am a complete newbie with canvas.
The program works when I scroll down, but it doesn't "return" when I scroll up.

(Excuse me also for my poor English)

this is the code:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" style="position:fixed;"></canvas>

<h1 style=" position: fixed;">scroll up and down to view the progress</h1>
<div id="content" style="height: 3000px;">


<!-- -----------------------SCRIPTS -----------------------  -->
<script>
    var body = document.body
    var myCanva = document.getElementById('canvas')
    window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
        let alto = body.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight
        let posY = window.scrollY
        let grados = (360 * (posY / alto)) //grados porcentuales según scroll

        let endAngle = (Math.PI / 180) * grados
        console.log(endAngle)
        const ctx = myCanva.getContext("2d")
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, endAngle)
        ctx.lineWidth = 20;
        ctx.stroke()

    }
    )
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `ctx.clearRect(0,0, myCanva.width, myCanva.height);` into the scroll event listener. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect

```js
    var body = document.body
    var myCanva = document.getElementById('canvas')
    window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
      let alto = body.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight
      let posY = window.scrollY
      let grados = (360 * (posY / alto)) //grados porcentuales según scroll

      let endAngle = (Math.PI / 180) * grados
      //console.log(endAngle)
      const ctx = myCanva.getContext("2d")
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanva.width, myCanva.height);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, endAngle)
      ctx.lineWidth = 20;
      ctx.stroke()

    })
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" style="position:fixed;"></canvas>

<h1 style=" position: fixed;">scroll up and down to view the progress</h1>
<div id="content" style="height: 3000px;"></div>
```